# << Operator overloading error in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm a C++ beginner, trying to learn from online videos. In of the operator overloading examples in the lectures the following code is there and gives the error

```
 error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << operator+(((point&)(& p1)), ((point&)(& p2)))'compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

on the line marked with comment. Can someone please tell what's wrong in the code? I am just trying what the professor explained in the lecture but can't compile.

===============

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class point{
public:
    double x,y;
};

point operator+ (point& p1, point& p2)
{
    point sum = {p1.x + p2.x, p1.y + p2.y};
    return sum;
}

ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, point& p)
{
    out << "("<<p.x<<","<<p.y<<")";
    return out;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    point p1 = {2,3};
    point p2 = {2,3};
    point p3;
    cout << p1 << p2;

    cout << p1+p2; // gives a compliation error
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a problem with const correctness.  Your operator+ returns a temporary, so you can't bind a non-`const` reference to it when calling `operator<<`.  Make the signature:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const point& p)
```

While you don't need to do it to fix this compilation error, you won't be able to add `const` points unless you fix the `operator+` similarly:

```
point operator+(const point& p1, const point& p2)
```

Comment: "Your operator+ returns a temporary, so you can't bind a non-const reference to it when calling operator<<" - 

That is not obvious. Is it somewhere in the C++ standard?

Comment: Thanks Tony for the detailed explanation.

Comment: @SergiiKhaperskov: it's covered in 8.5.3/5, see "Otherwise, the reference shall be an lvalue reference to a non-volatile const type (i.e., cv1 shall be const), or the reference shall be an rvalue reference." and the example "double& rd2 = 2.0; // error: not an lvalue and reference not const".

Answer (score 0):

Change the parameter type from `point&` to `const point&` for `operator+` and `operator<<`.  Non-const reference cannot bind to a temporary (which is returned by `operator+`) and that is causing the compile error.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the second parameter should be a const reference. (you don't want it gets modified, right?) So, it is like,

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, const Point &p)
{
    out << "(" << p.x << ", " << p.y << ")";

    return out;
}
```